# Why empty cell throws an error during SQL stored procedure execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
SELECT
    CAST ([content_html] AS XML).query('/root/Physicians/specialty/a') AS [Specialty1]
    , CAST ([content_html] AS XML).query('/root/Physicians/specialty2/a') AS [Specialty2]
    , CAST ([content_html] AS XML).query('/root/Physicians/specialty3/a') AS [Specialty3]
    , CAST ([content_html] AS XML).query('/root/Physicians/specialty4/a') AS [Specialty4]
    , CAST ([content_html] AS XML).query('/root/Physicians/specialty5/a') AS [Specialty5]
    , CAST ([content_html] AS XML).query('/root/Physicians/specialty6/a') AS [Specialty6]
FROM
    [db].[dbo].[content]
WHERE
    [folder_id] = '188'
    AND
    (content_status = 'A')
ORDER BY
    [content_title]
```

ASP.net repeater (partial):

```
<asp:Label ID="lblSpec1" runat="server"><%# Eval("Specialty1").ToString() + DisplayMultipleValues(Eval("Specialty2").ToString()) + DisplayMultipleValues(Eval("Specialty3").ToString()) + DisplayMultipleValues(Eval("Specialty4").ToString()) + DisplayMultipleValues(Eval("Specialty5").ToString()) + DisplayMultipleValues(Eval("Specialty6").ToString()) %></asp:Label>
```

C# (code that handles multiple entries and adds a `,`):

```
public string DisplayMultipleValues(string strValue)
{
    return (NonBlankValueOf(strValue));
}
public string NonBlankValueOf(string source)
{
    return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source)) ? "" : ", " + source;
}
```

When I run the query in SQL it works fine (If there is not value for the column, then it is an empty cell) but running it through code behind, gives me the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Specialty3'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Specialty3'.

Source Error: 


Line 96:                                     </div>
Line 97:                                     <div class="optionRight">
Line 98:                                         <asp:Label ID="lblSpec1" runat="server"><%# Eval("Specialty1").ToString() + DisplayMultipleValues(Eval("Specialty2").ToString()) + DisplayMultipleValues(Eval("Specialty3").ToString()) + DisplayMultipleValues(Eval("Specialty4").ToString()) + DisplayMultipleValues(Eval("Specialty5").ToString()) + DisplayMultipleValues(Eval("Specialty6").ToString()) %></asp:Label>
Line 99:                                     </div>
Line 100:                                </div>

Source File: c:\er.aspx    Line: 98 

Stack Trace: 


[HttpException (0x80004005): DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Specialty3'.]
   System.Web.UI.DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Object container, String propName) +12523742
   System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(Object container, String[] expressionParts) +142
   ASP.find_provider_aspx.__DataBind__control22(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\er.aspx:98
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +304
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +12746711
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +321
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +12746711
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +321
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateItem(Int32 itemIndex, ListItemType itemType, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem) +183
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource) +659
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +164
   find_provider.Search() in c:\er.aspx.cs:294
   find_provider.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\er.aspx.cs:37
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178
```

What is the best way to resolve it?

I tried the following:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblspec1" runat="server"><%# If(Eval("Specialty1").ToString() Is DBNull.Value, "", Eval("Specialty1").ToString()) + If(Eval("Specialty2").ToString() Is DBNull.Value, "", DisplayOffices(Eval("Specialty2").ToString())) + If(Eval("Specialty3").ToString() Is DBNull.Value, "", DisplayOffices(Eval("Specialty3").ToString())) + If(Eval("Specialty4").ToString() Is DBNull.Value, "", DisplayOffices(Eval("Specialty4").ToString())) + If(Eval("Specialty5").ToString() Is DBNull.Value, "", DisplayOffices(Eval("Specialty5").ToString())) + If(Eval("Specialty6").ToString() Is DBNull.Value, "", DisplayOffices(Eval("Specialty6").ToString())) %></asp:Label>
```

Comment: if (DBNull.Value == strValue)

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: If Eval("Specialty1") is null, then invoking ToString might be a problem. Try sth like Eval("Specialty1") != null ? Eval("Specialty").ToString() : ""

Comment: What about the rest of it? I am adding them all using `+` to make a whole list.

Comment: `Eval("Specialty1").ToString() == DBNull.Value) ? "" : Eval("Specialty1").ToString() + Eval("Specialty2").ToString() == DBNull.Value) ? "" : DisplayOffices(Eval("Specialty2").ToString()) + Eval("Specialty3").ToString() == DBNull.Value) ? "" : DisplayOffices(Eval("Specialty3").ToString()) + Eval("Specialty4").ToString() == DBNull.Value) ? "" : DisplayOffices(Eval("Specialty4").ToString()) + Eval("Specialty5").ToString() == DBNull.Value) ? "" : DisplayOffices(Eval("Specialty5").ToString()) + Eval("Specialty6").ToString() == DBNull.Value) ? "" : DisplayOffices(Eval("Specialty6").ToString())`

Comment: doesn't work either.

Comment: That is because you Are doing the ToString() before you are checking if the Value is DBNull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add something like this to the code behind of the page:

```
protected object MyEval(string expression)
{
    object o = null;
    try
    {
        o = DataBinder.Eval(this.GetDataItem(), expression);
    }
    catch
    {
        o = System.String.Empty;
    }
    return o;
}
```

and then replace all Evals with "MyEval":

```
<asp:Label ID="lblSpec1" runat="server"><%# MyEval("Specialty1").ToString() + DisplayMultiplMyEvalues(MyEval("Specialty2").ToString()) + DisplayMultiplMyEvalues(MyEval("Specialty3").ToString()) + DisplayMultiplMyEvalues(MyEval("Specialty4").ToString()) + DisplayMultiplMyEvalues(MyEval("Specialty5").ToString()) + DisplayMultiplMyEvalues(MyEval("Specialty6").ToString()) %></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case your problem is caused by NULL values, then you can solve your problem with sth like:

```
public string DisplayMultipleValues(object strValue)
{
   if (strValue == null)
      return "";
   else
      return (NonBlankValueOf(strValue.ToString()));
}
```

Your Eval statements should look like this:

```
<%# Eval("Specialty1") == null ? "" : Eval("Specialty1").ToString() + 
    DisplayMultipleValues(Eval("Specialty2")) + etc ...
```

Comment: The stack trace he provided doesn't mention ever getting into that function.  The error message states that it is failing on an Eval call because it can't find that column in the data set.

Comment: @Becuzz That's correct. The most propable cause of the error mentioned in the stack trace is a misspelling in the property name

Comment: @Becuzz That's why I started my answer by the phrase "In case your problem ..."

Comment: I actually have the same name as the column in sql

Answer (score 1):

As Gerbenny stated to say in the comments. DBNull won't be picked up by String.IsNullOrEmpty. DBNull is handled differently. to put it in code terms.

```
DBNull.Value != null
```

So basically You need to check if an Item is DBNull before trying to display or preforming any actions on it.

Essentially

```
    <%# Eval("Specialty1") != DBNull.Value ? Eval("Specialty1").ToString() : String.Empty + DisplayMultipleValues(Eval("Specialty2") != DBNull.Value ? Eval("Specialty2").ToString() : String.Empty)
 + etc... %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace and error message you provided state exactly why it isn't working.  It says

```
DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Specialty3'.
```

which is coming out of

```
...
System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(Object container, String[] expressionParts) +142
...
```

which means it is erroring where you are doing `Eval("Specialty3")`.

What all this boils down to is that the data set coming back from your database doesn't contain a column named Specialty3.  It could be from a misspelling, from not updating a proc or for a number of other reasons.

Comment: The partial sql shows I do hence why I find it odd that I get this error.